# Метку [execute] нельзя помиловать

Tags: предложение, удаление-метки

Под меткой [execute](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execute) смешались в кучу:

- Вопросы о методе `execute` из VK API

  - ([vkontakte-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vkontakte-api) достаточно)
  - Превалируют именно они, но почти все созданы одним автором.
- Запуск программ из других программ (в т. ч.  системный вызов `exec`)

  - (особая метка не нужна; куда полезнее метки средства [языка?] и среды [ОС?])
- `max_execution_time` из PHP

  - ([php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) достаточно)
- `Executor`ы из Java

  - ([java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) достаточно, может ещё [многопоточность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c))

Пока этих вопросов немного (23), метку ещё можно выжечь малой кровью.

Что будем делать с этой меткой?

Удаляем? Оставляем с предупреждением о неоднозначности и пометкой **не использовать**? Загоняем в чёрный список?

Comment: Заново возвращаюсь к данному вопросу: Вопросов уже 34, добавились вопросы связанные с базами данных. Будем ли как-то решать данный вопрос?

Answer (score 6):

> Удаляем? Оставляем с предупреждением о неоднозначности и пометкой не
>   использовать? Загоняем в чёрный список?

Как по мне - на все три вопроса ответ "да", разве что с [чёрным списком](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43749497#43749497) придётся повозиться:

> Q: А у вас нет полномочий вносить метки в чёрный список или хотя бы их
>   автоматически удалять?
>
> Nicolas Chabanovsky: На сколько я знаю, это могут делать всего три
>   человека (могу ошибаться): Джош, Джон, Тим. Почему именно они и можно
>   ли мне получить этот доступ, я никогда не узнавал. На момент, когда
>   присоединился к команде, все было так и оно всех устраивает, на
>   сколько я понимаю.